# How to code parallel computing process in C# 4.0

Tags: c#-4.0, parallel-processing

How to achieve parallel computing process in C# 4.0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By using [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163340.aspx), for example.

Answer (score 2):

All of the parallelization options in .NET 3.5 will exist in C# 4.0.

However, the Task Parallel Library will be moved into System.Threading directly as part of the BCL.  This will allow constructs like Parallel.For loops, using the new TaskScheduler, etc.

Also, PLINQ will be included in the BCL in .NET 4, which allows for parallel queries to be run.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the Task Parallel Library on VS 2008 by downloading the CTP here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=348F73FD-593D-4B3C-B055-694C50D2B0F3&displaylang=en

Or you can try the Dev 10 beta here if you're an MSDN subscriber:

[see comment SO thinks I'm a spammer]

There are changes between the two versions in terms of namespaces and some APIs have been tweaked but either will get you started.

Ade

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=85520793-68fc-4361-a8b6-dc2cff49c8d2&displaylang=en